# how create select query to get all the child node of any particular node in tree structure db table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jakarta-ee, qsqlquery

My Tree Structure is[image]

and the database table i have created is [image]

how create select query to get all the child node of any particular node in tree structure db table.

for Example i pass superior_emp_id=1  then it return {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

Comment: Why if you pass 1 then you will get `{2,3,4,5,6,7}` what relation you have inbetween?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from employee 
where superior_emp_id = @emp_id  

union all  

select * 
from employee 
where superior_emp_id in (select emp_id 
                          from employee 
                          where superior_emp_id = @emp_id)
```

Comment: java baba - would you mind letting me know whether this is working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make use of nested queries and sets here,

You can try the following query for getting the child nodes of root node:

```
select *
from TABLE_NAME
where senior_emp_id in { select emp_id
                         from TABLE_NAME
                         where senior_emp_id = 1 || emp_id = 1 }
```

Similarly if you put 2 in place of 1 in the nested query  if you want to have child nodes of Parent node -2

Let me know if it's working well ..

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("SELECT emp_id AS id, ");
        sql.append("  emp_name AS employeeName, ");
        sql.append("  title AS title, ");
        sql.append("  superior_emp_id AS parentId ");
        sql.append(" FROM T_NWM_SRVC ");
        sql.append(" WHERE superior_emp_id IS NOT NULL ");
        sql.append(" AND superior_emp_id  =");
        sql.append(parentId);
```

> On passing **parentId : 1** you will retrieve 2,3.For getting childnodes of 2,3 you will have to do a server call again(Kind of lazy loading).
>   Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cant do this with one sql Statement. I would try to implement a recursive function that querys for a set of given ids if there more childs and append them. 
Prosa:

```
function List<Integer> getChilds(int[] ids)
{  
List<Integer> returnValue = new ArrayList();
if(ids.length = 0)
    return returnValue;

foreach int id : ids
{
    //Build sql to get childs an execute it
    int[] childidsfromsql = em.createQuery("...").getResultList();..
    returnValue.addAll(getChilds(childidsfromsql))
}
 return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: try using List only, and do not convert from int array to list xD i hope u can understand the idea behind this prosa code